Firebase Messaging: "UNREGISTERED" Error When Sending Notifications to Multiple Devices
I'm facing an issue with Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) where I get an UNREGISTERED error on one device when I send a notification to another device. Here’s a summary of my setup and the issue:

I have an Android application using Firebase for push notifications.
Each device receives a unique FCM token when initialized, and these tokens are stored on my backend.
When I send a notification to one device, the other device’s token becomes UNREGISTERED, causing notifications to stop working on that device.
This problem only occurs when there are multiple devices; with a single device, everything works as expected.

What I've Tried

Ensured Tokens are Unique: Each device retrieves its token via FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken() and logs show unique tokens.
Forced Token Regeneration: I used deleteToken() followed by getToken() on each device to ensure distinct tokens are generated.

Despite these steps, the UNREGISTERED error still occurs consistently when sending notifications to multiple devices.
What could be causing the UNREGISTERED error on one device when notifications are sent to another? Is there any other configuration or method in FCM to ensure each device maintains a unique, valid token without interfering with others?
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Ok, I think I found a solution. I created and configured a new application in Firebase, and it seems to be working now.
